# numpy bring values in a range

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Is there a more elegant way of bringing values in a numpy array in the range 0-50?

```
x = np.array([-5, 6, 24, 51, 50, 40])
array([-5,  6, 24, 51, 50, 40])

x = np.where(x < 0, 0, x)
x = np.where(x > 50, 50, x)

array([ 0,  6, 24, 50, 50, 40])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [49]: x = np.array([-5, 6, 24, 51, 50, 40])
```

A couple of alternatives:

```
In [50]: np.clip(x,0,50)
Out[50]: array([ 0,  6, 24, 50, 50, 40])

In [52]: np.minimum(np.maximum(x,0),50)
Out[52]: array([ 0,  6, 24, 50, 50, 40])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out there is https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html#numpy.clip

```
np.clip(x, 0, 50)
array([ 0,  6, 24, 50, 50, 40])
```